# Remove Memory Optimisation on a sql table and also delete the filegroup created by it

Tags: sql, ssms

I have few databases which are memory optimized. Any suggestions on how to remove the memory optimization and also delete the filegroups of the memory optimization on it.

Thanks

Comment: Last time I looked at this it was a one-way process, you are stuck with the filegroup.

Comment: Yes, stuck with the file group. Any suggestions on how to remove it.